# Dynamic Access Controls limit user access to file based on file metadata and SQL Server table

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-permissions, windows

I'm looking into Dynamic Access Controls as a way to limit user access to files in my file share, but I don't know if it can do what I am trying to do.

All of the files in my share have custom metadata that describe the category the file falls into (Finance, Project 1, Project 2, Human Resources, etc.) I also have an SQL table that holds `Username -> Category` key value pairs.

Is there a way to build a policy that that determines access based on something like this:

```
File.Category ANY_OF SQL_Table[Username]
```

Where `SQL_Table[Username]` is a list of all of the categories the user has access to, as recorded in the SQL table?

I don't want to use Security Groups because I don't want everyone to know who is in what projects, and creating a Security Group would expose the membership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Access Control (DAC) doesn't have any functionality to use SQL Server as a source for authorization information like you're describing. The current versions of the product just don't do that.

Active Directory attributes and file classification properties are the only factors that DAC can take into account when making an authorization decision. You're stuck either using an existing AD attribute or extending the schema to create a new attribute to do what you're looking for.

Hiding security group membership isn't a completely lost cause, though you're definitely changing the default behavior of the product. The US Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act (FERPA) has caused some need in the higher education community for AD groups with hidden membership. There have been some discussions on the [ActiveDir.org](http://www.activedir.org/) mailing list about this in the past. The University of Washington Windows Infrastructure article on [Course Group Privacy Configuration](http://www.netid.washington.edu/documentation/courseGroupPrivacy.aspx) would be something to look at, too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information!  Very thorough answer